# Is it possible for my Android App to be notified when an Android user setting has been updated?

Tags: android

My app does not work without Notification Access, and I want to display a warning when it is on or off.

Is there a way I can monitor this setting without just polling it? Like is there something I can subscribe to that will automatically update me what this setting is changed?

I have tried the following code, but it is not updated when I update the setting.

```
var contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        val setting = Settings.System.getUriFor(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS)
        val observer: ContentObserver = object : ContentObserver(Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())) {
            override fun onChange(selfChange: Boolean) {
                super.onChange(selfChange)
            }

            override fun deliverSelfNotifications(): Boolean {
                return true
            }
        }

        contentResolver.registerContentObserver(setting, false, observer);
```

Comment: It looks like you can utilize the [NotificationManager][1].  There are several intents you can register for there that might fit your use case.

Comment: Do you have a concrete example?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're requiring Notification Access, then you have a class that extends `NotificationListenerService`. You just need to override `onListenerConnected()` -- it only gets called once the ListenerService is connected, and that only happens when Notification Access is approved.

```
class ListenerService: NotificationListenerService() {
    ...
    override fun onListenerConnected() {
        super.onListenerConnected()
        // if you get here, then Notification Access was approved
    }
    ...
}
```